# Error: Change visibility of ''title'' to 'default' or Replace Bookinfo.title with getter

Tags: android, android-intent, visibility, fragment

I'm getting this error on within my fragment on the Bookinfo.title, Bookinfo.author and Book.isbn variables.  I have no idea why. All the documentation just gives me another error when trying to correct it.  As for Bookinf, it has another class that consists of getters and setters. I'm getting an error on the word Fragment in the class BookDetailsFragment.  Error says add @SuppressLint 'NewApi' to BookDetailsFragment. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Here's my code for the BookDetailsFragment:

```
import android.app.Fragment;

public class BookDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_details, container, false);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_details, null);


    System.out.println("BookDetailsActivity executed");

    //Defines the TextViews in R.layout.book_details
    TextView bkTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bookTitle);
    TextView bkAuth = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bookAuthor);
    TextView bkIsbn = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.bookISBN);


    //Retrieve the bundle object passed from BuyFragTab
    Bundle b = getArguments();


    //Getting the item's clicked position and setting corresponding details

    bkTitle.setText("Title:    " + Bookinfo.title[b.getInt("position")]);
    bkAuth.setText("Author:    " + Bookinfo.author[b.getInt("position")]);
    bkIsbn.setText("ISBN:      " + Bookinfo.isbn[b.getInt("position")]);

    return view;
    }

}
```

Here's the Bookinfo class code:

```
package com.skipster.BookBarter;

public class Bookinfo {
private String title;
private String author;
private String isbn;


public Bookinfo(String title, String author, String isbn) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.isbn = isbn;

            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }
    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    //returns all the previous variables to the program that made the call
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title + " " + author + " " + isbn;
    }
}
```

Here's the code for BookDetailsActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class BookDetailsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //setting the layout for this activity
    setContentView(R.layout.book_details_activity_layout);

    //get fragment manager for fragment related operations
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    //get fragment transaction object, which can add, move or replace a fragmnt
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    //instantiating the fragment BookDetailsFragment
    BookDetailsFragment detailsFragment = new BookDetailsFragment();

    //creating a bundle object to pass the data (clicked item's position)
    //from this activity to fragment
    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    //setting the data to the bundle object from the Intent
    b.putInt("position", getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0));
    System.out.println("the bundle passed" + b);

    //setting the bundle object to the fragment
    detailsFragment.setArguments(b);

    //adding the fragment to the fragment transaction
    ft.add(R.id.book_details_fragment_container, detailsFragment);

    //add the fragment transaction to backstack
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    //Executing the transaction
    ft.commit();
}
}
```

Here's the code for the onClickListener that starts the intent:

```
bookLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id){

        String selectTitle, selectAuthor, selectIsbn = null;

        //When item is clicked, show it's detailed view
        Bookinfo bkRecs = (Bookinfo)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


        //Creating an intent object to start BookDetailsActivity
        Intent bkIntent = new Intent("com.skipster.BookBarter.BOOKDETAILSACTIVITY");

        //Setting data (the clicked item's position to the intent
        bkIntent.putExtra("position", position);

        System.out.println("Data loaded for intent");
        //Start the activity
        startActivity(bkIntent);

        System.out.println("Intent activity started");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragment class was added in API 11. Looks like your minSDK version is older than this. If you want to use Fragments in an older SDK, you should use support library, which gives you support for Fragments..

For Support library Refer : http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Comment: I thought having a minSkdString"7" and targetedSdkVersion="15" would encompass this.

Comment: you'd need support library along with that sdk versions.